# Angular ui-select ng-blur

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using `ui-select` and want to use `ng-blur` on ui select, but the function I am trying to call on `ng-blur` is not triggering.
`ng-blur` is not working on `ui-select`.

```
<ui-select ng-blur="getdetails()" ng-model="$root.caseSearchModel.progressionDesc"
skip-focusser="true" id="current_progression_description">
    <ui-select-match>
        <span ng-bind-html="$select.selected.DESC1"></span>
    </ui-select-match>
    <ui-select-choices repeat="item.DESC2 as item in progressionDescs | filter: { DESC2: $select.search }">
        <div ng-bind-html="item.DESC1 | highlight: $select.search"></div>
    </ui-select-choices>
    <ui-select-no-choice>
        Does not match.
    </ui-select-no-choice>
</ui-select>
$scope.getdetails = function () {
    console.log("i am in blur function");
}
```

I want to trigger the function `getdetails` every time the user leaves the `ui-select`.

Comment: You mean to say after selecting some option or just open select and close?

Comment: After going through the docs https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/ui-select I did not find the blur attribute in it. Use the attributes mentioned in docs.

Comment: witch version of ui-select are you using?? they have provided work around in 0.19.0 version : https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/uis-open-close

Comment: Why do you want to use ng-blur over ui-select?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not very clear what do you want but, if you want to take some detail about selected item, you can use this event:

```
<ui-select on-select="getDetails($item, $model)"> ... </<ui-select>
```

Answer (score 1):

With version 0.19.0 of `ui-select`, you can pass a directive called `uis-open-close` to which you can pass a callback that is called whenever the dropdown is opened or closed.

It contain `isOpen` as an argument which is set to true if the dropdown has been opened, otherwise false.

https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-select/wiki/uis-open-close